# Best OO design implementation in C++?

Tags: c++, oop

This is more about taste maybe.

Something like this:

```
class A:public vector<int>{};

class B:public vector<A>{
};

class C{
public:
vector<B> cs;
};
```

Now I want to implement is a function in `A` which receives an object of `C`. Something like this:

```
class A:vector<int>{
void foo( C &c);
};
```

This is not possible because `C` needs `B` and `B` needs `A` to be declared fully. Then I see 2 options:

1) Make foo so: `void foo(void *c);` and on the implementation (in the A.cpp) make the casting. The problem of this is not really nice or clean, and little bit confusing for other developers.

2) Make an object on the namespace I am working on. This violates the SOLID principles particularly Single responsibility principle.

Maybe there is a third way that I don’t see and it dose not have inconvenient. Anyone can tell me if there is a more correct form of any of dose?

Comment: How about a plain old forward declaration?

Comment: Firstly, in C++03 at least it's undefined behaviour to have a `vector<C>` in `C`.  Secondly, you can declare `class C;` above `A` to let you define `A` with that declaration of `foo`.  You should put the definition of `foo` after class `C`'s.

Comment: Don't inherit from `std::vector`. It doesn't have a virtual destructor (which may or may not be a problem), but just making it a member will definitely improve your design.

Comment: Thanks I had never used before on classes.

Comment: Sorry, the vector<C> on C was a copy past error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use forward declaration:

```
class C;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I see your problem.  There's no problem with:

```
class C;
class A
{
    void foo( C& c );
};
```

(There is a problem with your `C`, however.  A class `C` cannot
contain a `std::vector<C>`, since `std::vector` requires that
the instantiation type be complete, and `C` is only complete
after the closing brace.)